# All Google Drive files have disappeared

Tags: google-drive

My girlfriend's Google Drive account has been completely wiped out excluding one file. Last summer she started writing her thesis then she didn't touch it for a while. When she came back to it today all the files went missing ( all the files not related to the thesis as well ). Trash is empty. Activity log shows no sign of the files. We called up google and they said they can see that we have 270 MB worth of files in the drive but we only see around 170 MB. Anyone come across anything like this before? Are they somehow hidden? She doesn't backup her files anywhere and no syncing is turned on.

What other steps can we take to hopefully find these files?

Comment: Using your girlfriend account go to https://drive.google.com/drive/quota. What you see there?

Comment: @Rubén 3 files that add up to 170 MB

Comment: Besides the list of files that are in "My Drive" that show the total storage used by GDrive, GMail and Google Photos. If you don't see the same than the person from Google it might be possible that someone is looking at the wrong account. Before calling again Google try using Chrome in incognito mode.